# How to remove title from woocommerce_single_product_summary hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On my product template, I execute this action :

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
    */
   do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');
?>
```

What I want is do remove the `woocommerce_template_single_title`  hook so in my **functions.php** file I wrote this code :

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 1);
```

But it does not work and I don't know how.

Thanks for your help

**!! EDIT !!**

**Nevermind I solved it by writing this:**

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
```

**The priority have to match**

Comment: You should post the edit as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

> The author has added the one-liner to his question; as suggested by @Bugs, here it is as an answer.

---

```
// Remove title hook Woocommerce
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
```

Comment: Note that for each, it appears you need to match the priority. So in the content-single-product.php the `woocommerce_template_single_title` is set to `5` but `woocommerce_template_single_rating` is set to `10`. Matching that in the code above does the trick.